# Randomize image position with JQuery and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transition

I have this :

```
<div id="randomp" style="position:absolute;top:3px;left:3px;width:165px;height:29px;background:url(/logo2.png) no-repeat;background-size: 165px;"></div>
```

I want that the propierty "top" and "left" change every time you enter into the page. I mean that some times it appear on the right top corner, right bottom corner, left top corner and left bottom corner..

Here it is what i have tryied: 
http://redzer.com.mx/tabla.html

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I'm not too sure if this will work, but conceptually, have an array of positions (maybe 2D so it correlates XY nicely) and when the page loads, `top:x_pixel` etc etc

Comment: How can i do that? im so confused :S

Comment: Put the locations into an array. When the page loads, randomly choose a position from the array and place those values into the style attribute. Like I said, I don't know if the style will parse js variables, so you would have to dynamically modify the image position with javascript/jquery. If you don't understand that, you might be a little in over your head

Comment: Yeah i understood about the arrays but i dont know how to do that im not good in javascript :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably start with the div styled as `position:fixed` and with `display:none`:

```
<div id="randomp" style="display:none;position:fixed;width:165px;height:29px;background:url(/logo2.png) no-repeat;background-size: 165px;"></div>
```

Then use jQuery to determine the position CSS to set and turn on visibility

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get jQuery object for the div
    var $randomp = $('#randomp');
    // determine whether to show top or bottom, left or right
    var top = Math.round(Math.random()); // generate 0 or 1 value
    if (top === 1) {
        $randomp.css('top', '3px');
    } else {
        $randomp.css('bottom', '3px');
    }       
    var left = Math.round(Math.random());
    if (left === 1) {
        $randomp.css('left', '3px');
    } else {
        $randomp.css('right', '3px');
    }
    // show the div
    $randomp.show();
});
```

Of course, you could also use server-side code to do this, but since you asked specifically about javascript/jquery in your tags, I suggested this solution.

Comment: @Xcite Sorry didn't realize I didn't have enough space before the HTML section of my answer so it didn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got exactly what you need.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/jLmzk/1/)**

With javascript i am generating random numbers for the top and left positioning of your image every time you visit the page.
Right now i set them up to get a random number between 0 and 100 but you can change that to whatever you want.

```
var random1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
var random2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#randomp').css('top', random1);
    $('#randomp').css('left', random2);

});
```